# StrSplit will not accept `n as a delimiter

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to read strings off a CSV, which I want send to other applications using a hot string.
I want to use each row of my CSV as a string in an array, so I figured I would use the the newline (`n) character as my delimiter

Currently the relevant bit of my script reads:

```
FileString=""
FileRead, FileString, *t Constants.csv
ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues:=StrSplit(FileString,`n, )
LoopLength = ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues.Length()
```

However, when I try to run it, it gives me an error

```
the following variable name contains an illegal character
"
"
the script was not reloaded;...
```

I have tried replacing the `n with

```
"`n", %`n%, "%`n%", `r
```

and so on. and it just won't accept it.

I have also tried setting `ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues = StrSplit(...)` but then when I go to use `looplength` later it returns literal "ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues.Length()" as a string.

Lastly, I have read the docs and noticed that you're technically supposed to use `loop,parse,` to improve performance but for me this is more of an exercise in understanding how arrays work, than it is in squeezing performance out of the program (I'm very new to scripting and/or programming languages).

I realize I'm probably doing something dumb, but I've been beating my head against this for hours, and am completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few mistakes in here, all of them pretty much just about you not knowing the syntax.
Might be good to try to learn the syntax first.

So, lets start from the first line.
`FileString=""`
You're using the legacy way assigning text to a variable. The variable `FileString` now holds the literal text `""`.
To fix this, you're going to want to get rid of legacy syntax and never use it again.
[`:=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm) is used to assign an expression's result to a variable. The expression being `""`, which evaluates to *nothing*.

Second line is fine I guess. Though, I'd ditch the usage of the legacy command and switch over to [`FileOpen()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileOpen.htm).
Also, there was actually no need to define the variable `FileString` before you passed into that command. That was redundant.

Third line, you're now using the correct operator to assign a value.
So the mistake in this line is that you're in expression syntax. Not in legacy syntax.
In the newer and better expression syntax you specify a string (or in your case, just a character) by wrapping it in `""`. Like you tried to do on first line.
Then you have a trailing comma in there. I don't know what it's supposed to be about, but it's just a straight up syntax error.
So here's the fixed line:
`` ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues := StrSplit(FileString, "`n") ``

And in the fourth line you got the wrong operator again. You're not assigning literal text to variable, as you do in legacy syntax. You're assigning the result of an expression.

Here's the whole thing fixed:

```
FileString := FileOpen("Constants.csv", "r `n").Read()
ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues := StrSplit(FileString, "`n")
LoopLength := ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues.Length()
```

Or, with the legacy `FileRead` command:

```
FileString := "" ;this line is redundant
FileRead, FileString, *t Constants.csv
ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues := StrSplit(FileString, "`n")
LoopLength := ArrayOfCommaSeperatedValues.Length()
```

Important thing to notice, is that in the legacy command we're using the legacy syntax. String are not wrapped around in `""`.

Here's a good documentation page about the AHK scripting language. Explains the difference between legacy and expression syntax as well. Which is one of the problems you seem to have have had trouble with as well.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm

The "beginner tutorial" should also be a good read:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm

Comment: Can you clarify that the OP's main problem on line 3 was the extra comma and not the ``​`n``, which they tried in double quotes also? If so, I'm tempted to close this as caused by a typo.

Comment: Not really sure what the intention with the comma was. Seems like they were just guessing a lot of stuff. But sure, I guess it's the "main" problem, though even with having fixed it, the code still wouldn't have worked due to the other problems in it.

Comment: i think the extra comma came from me trying to use the omit chars parameter in strsplit, and then not realising it could be removed. It's safe to say the problem i came here with is solved